# Create a spring project,maven,spring data jpa,web

Tags: xml, spring, spring-data

I have been searching online and there's so much stuf; yet I can't find something appropriate.
What I basically want to do is create a spring project that uses html or whatever on the front end and java,spring data with restful on the back end.
I can't seem to find a tutorial giving information about this.
Some exmplain one thing but not the other. 
Are there good tutorial that show how to use these technologies together, that also explain how to configure xml files, beans etc?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Spring Tool Suite. STS will give you numerous project templates to choose from and you can find the appropriate one among the types of projects.

For your other query about tutorials, If you want to learn spring I would strongly recommend
[Spring in action - manning](http://www.manning.com/walls4/) and once you are good with the basics of spring you can refer to all the guides [here](https://spring.io/guides)
Just checkout a projcet from github according to those guides and learn by doing.
Hope that helps.